# namespaced toggling for CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery has this function

- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

but it does not allow name-spacing.  With name-spacing you can toggle between multiple classes as if they were radio buttons.

for example

```
toggleClass(el, 'ns1', 'test')
```

will check `ns1` and will remove any other class with this namespace and replace it with the class `test`

I wrote this library function to keep my application code.

One mistake I made was I prefixed the class with the namespace rather then make it a separate argument.

Here is my in progress use of a custom toggleClass with name-spacing:

```
// apply event listeners to the input elements
applyEL: function (input_element, label_element) {
    var self = this;
    self.J.input = $(input_element);
    self.J.input.on("blur", function () {
        if (input_element.value === '') {
            $A.toggleClass(input_element, self.S.toggle_border_show);
            $A.toggleClass(label_element, self.S.toggle_label_show);
            $A.expandFont(label_element, 'up', self.S.speed);
        }
    }, false);
    self.J.input.on("focus", function () {
        if (input_element.value === '') {
            $A.toggleClass(input_element, self.S.toggle_border_obscure);
            $A.toggleClass(label_element, self.S.toggle_label_obscure);
        }
    }, false);
    self.J.input.on("paste keypress drop", function () {
        $A.setTimeout(function (label_element, input_element) {
            $A.toggleClass(label_element, this.S.toggle_label_hide);
            $A.toggleClass(input_element, this.S.toggle_border_hide);
        }, 0);
    }, false);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, other from what I mentioned.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. I googled "html class namespace", and can't find any suggestion that classes are in namespaces.

Comment: classes aren't namespaced, so this makes no sense, how would a class be namespaced and what the heck are you trying to do ?

Comment: I wish to understand what you're doing, but there is too much undefined variables here...

Comment: @Karl - `this.S.toggle_label_hide` is just a string literal equal to `'toggle_label_hide'`, the others follow suit, `label` is the namespace and `hide` is the value in this case. The word namespace is used loosely.

Comment: Your example suggests that there are three parameters to your custom function, but then you go ahead and say "Here is my use of a custom toggleClass" but then you clearly use the built-in jQuery .toggleClass method.

Comment: what about adding a class for namespacing to elements then selecting the class with `$('.namespacedClass.selector')` Do you have some HTML so we can better understand the problem, maybe a jsbin or jsfiddle? The signature looks wrong to me. I've never seen a selector in .toggleClass. Is that the "namespace"?

Comment: @sahbeewah - I am not using jQuery, it is custom, but I am considering switching over, however, it would add lines of code, so I might just stick with the custom solution.

Comment: @Shanimal - The only thing I see wrong is that instead of using multiple parameters, I combined them into a string and separated them with an underscore... also prefix "toggle_" seems a bit superfulous ...  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Better way would be, rather add a class to html or body element, which would act as a name space, much like common theme switchers?

And if you need a local name space for a specific element you would reference the parent element.

And boom, you have name spaces!